# Calling classes without creating objects

Tags: java, object, new-operator

I know that there is memory allocation when we create an object of a class as follows:

> Test t = new Test();
>     t.method1();

But I can call mehtod1 as follows too:

> new Test().method1();

So, in the second of way calling the method1, is there memory allocated. because apparently I am not creating an object here.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently you **are** creating an object. You're just not assigning it to a variable, but an object is created by the new call on the constructor just the same.

Comment: The `new` operator allocates memory, and you're still using `new`. If it didn't allocate memory, what do you think `this` references inside the `method1` method?

Comment: You're not calling classes but methods of classes. The only methods you can call without creating objects are static methods.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is **yes**.  The code `new Test()` creates an object, which happens to be an instance of the `Test` class.  Memory is allocated on the heap for *every* object that you create, whether you assign it to a variable or not.

Of course, like all memory on the heap, that memory is available for garbage collection as soon as there's no reference to that object anywhere in scope.  If you don't assign it to a variable, then the reference created by the expression `new Test()` goes out of scope as soon as it's used.  This means the memory might get garbage collected quite quickly.  But it's certainly allocated.